# Scroll horizontal datatable

Tags: html, datatables

Saludos he intentado implementar la barra horizontal en datatables sin exito se visualiza de la siguiente manera:
[image: datable]

El codigo javascript:

```
 $('#table_estadofacturas').DataTable({

        fixedHeader: {
            header: true,
            headerOffset: 45,
            },
        scrollX: true
    });
```

estructura de mi tabla html:

```
  <table class="table" id="table_estadofacturas" >
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr bgcolor="#bee5eb">
                                            <td class="text-center">#</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">Factura</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">Datos Emisor</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">Datos SRI</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">Ambiente</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">Estado</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">SRI</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">Cliente</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {% for respuestasri in respuestasri_list %}
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                                                <td><span class="badge bg-aqua">{{ respuestasri.secuencia.numero_secuencia }}</span></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar text-blue"></i> Fecha de Emisión: <br> {{ respuestasri.fec_emision|date:"d-m-Y" }}<br>
                                                    <i class="fa fa-barcode text-olive"></i> Clave Generada:<br><svg id="barcode_{{ forloop.counter }}"></svg>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar text-blue"></i> Fec. Autorización <br>{{ respuestasri.fec_autorizacion|date:"d-m-Y H:m:s" }}<br>
                                                    <i class="fa fa-barcode text-olive"></i> Nro, Autorización <br><svg id="barcode_autorizacion_{{ forloop.counter }}"></svg><br>

                                                </td>
                                                {% if respuestasri.ambiente == 1 %}
                                                    <td><span class="badge bg-purple">PRUEBA</span></td>
                                                {% else %}
                                                    <td><span class="badge bg-blue">PRODUCCIÓN</span></td>
                                                {% endif %}
                                                {% if respuestasri.estado == 1 %}
                                                    <td><span class="badge bg-green">AUTORIZADO</span></td>
                                                {% elif respuestasri.estado == 2 %}
                                                    <td><span class="badge bg-yellow">PENDIENTE</span></td>
                                                {% else %}
                                                    <td><span class="badge bg-yellow">NO AUTORIZADO</span></td>
                                                {% endif %}
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="reenviarFactura('{{ respuestasri.pk }}');">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-send-o text-green"> </i> SRI
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="EnviarCliente('{{ respuestasri.pk }}');">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-send-o text-info"></i> CLIENTE
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

He probado distintas soluciones pero sin efectos como:

```
$(".table ").css({"width":"100%"});
```

tambien esta:

```
.datatable-scroll {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

quiza alguien me podria decir que estoy haciendo mal, gracias de antemano.